# Time Update in HomePage Meta Description

Tags: homepage

every time I add a new post my blog homepage also shows the update time in Meta.

Say whenever i type site:thetopblogger.com in Google search it shows update time in homepage Meta description - 1 hour ago, 4 hours ago, 15 hours ago, 3 days ago, 5 days ago which matches with the last post add/update.

I check many blogs but no one is showing any time in homepage Meta. I do not want to show time in Homepage Meta description, as Google will think that I refresh/update my homepage meta frequently!

Any idea how to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using Structured Data/Rich Snippets on your pages.

Front page contains many snippets such as:

> entry-title: Google PageRank Update History Timeline
>
> entry-content: Google PageRank is the most highly rated and awaited factors on which every blogger keeps a close eye and eagerly wait to see the result of their favorite blog! Looking back, somewhere on a...
>
> published:    2013-05-02
>
> author:    fn:    Taswir Haider

If you want to remove the time stamp element then you need to remove:

```
<abbr class="published" title="2013-05-02">May 2, 2013</abbr>
```

Google is very good at establishing when you up date your pages so regardless if this is in there or not it will have a rough idea. The idea of Rich content is to provide more accurate information as well more information.

You can review your Structured Data Here: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thetopblogger.com%2F&html=